# Xamarin Android BottomBarBadge doesn't properly display counts of 100+

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I try to display a count higher than 99 in the `BottomBarBadge`, it won't be displayed correctly because there is not enough space in the Badge.

This screenshot shows a badge which actually contains a count of 110, but it looks like "11" because the "0" is cut off by the small badge:

[image]

The problem is that when the count changes, I just set the new `badge.Count` like this:

```
badge.Count = int.Parse(text);
```

At this point, I expect the badge to automatically render it's new width to fit the new count if it needs a new height (e.g. changed from 99 to 100 or the other way around). But that doesn't seem to happen.

Is there a method or some other thing I am missing which updates the badge's width?

I expect the badge to stretch a bit in it's width if needed, like in WhatsApp:

[image]

I am using the 3rd Party BottomNavigationBar by pocheshire: https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar

---

### EDIT:

Using [Sushi Hangover's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675807/xamarin-android-bottombarbadge-doesnt-properly-display-counts-of-100/50676666#50676666) did work, but it broke something else. When I tap on a tab which contains a badge, the app will crash in a `NullReferenceException`:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at BottomNavigationBar.BottomBar.HandleClick (Android.Views.View v) [0x00010] in <f60603cf39c84bebb4c6ba69e7e8bb64>:0 
  at BottomNavigationBar.BottomBar+<MakeBadgeForTabAt>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 () [0x00011] in <f60603cf39c84bebb4c6ba69e7e8bb64>:0 
  at BottomNavigationBar.Listeners.OnTabClickListener.OnClick (Android.Views.View v) [0x0000d] in <f60603cf39c84bebb4c6ba69e7e8bb64>:0 
  at Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_v) [0x0000f] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.30ced559-6971-4697-bb8d-82a961a4b1e9(intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

I could not find a mistake in the Custom Renderer, I did set breakpoints at every line of code which calls `MakeBadgeForTabAt()`, but it didn't execute this code before the Exception occured.

This is the code which seems to causes the exception:

```
protected virtual void OnTabbedPagePropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var page = sender as Page;
    if (page == null)
        return;

    if (e.PropertyName == TabBadge.BadgeTextProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        if (CheckValidTabIndex(page, out int tabIndex))
        {
            var element = Element.Children[tabIndex];
            UpdateTabBadgeText(BadgeViews[element], page);
        }
        return;
    }
}

private void UpdateTabBadgeText(BottomBarBadge badge, Element element)
{
    var text = TabBadge.GetBadgeText(element);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        try
        {
            // This does not cause an exception, but doesn't update the badge's size:
            // badge.Count = int.Parse(text);

            // This causes NullReferenceException when taping the tab:
            var index = Element.Children.IndexOf((Page)element);
            _bottomBar.RemoveBadgeAt(index);
            _bottomBar.MakeBadgeForTabAt(index, "#FF0000", int.Parse(text));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // exception handling
        }
    }
    if (badge.Count == 0)
    {
        badge.Hide(false);
    }
    else
    {
        badge.Show(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the 3rd party `BottomBar`?

Comment: Yes, edited my question

Comment: That is a ported version of the Java version that is deprecated and that issue was in the original. A workaround is to remove the badge when the value goes over 99 and add it again instead of just increasing the count

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation! Your workaround works. Feel free to add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks for hanging around so often in Xamarin questions, I've learned a lot from your answers so many times :)

Comment: Edited my question because the workaround causes a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a ported version of the Java version that is deprecated and that issue was in the original.

A workaround is to remove the badge when the value goes over 99 and add it again instead of just increasing the count.

I have not looked at the C# version, but assume the code of `BottomBarBadge.java` is the "same" and the size of the badge view is only calculated once during the `attachToTab` method. So the workaround works since the `attachToTab/adjustPositionAndSize` flow is called again, but the badge contents should really be checked  to determine if they would  overflow the badge circle and re-call the `adjustPositionAndSize`, ...I think... ;-)

re: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/bottom-bar/src/main/java/com/roughike/bottombar/BottomBarBadge.java#L94

#### Update:

There are a bunch of issues/bugs with removing/recreating a badge, etc.. in that library (which is slightly different than the original Java library).

While this should be in the library itself, you can do this to properly resize the badge when setting the count:

```
void ResetBadgeCount(BottomBarBadge badge, int count)
{
    badge.Count = count;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lparams;
    using (var bounds = new Rect())
    {
        badge.Paint.GetTextBounds(badge.Text, 0, badge.Text.Length, bounds);
        lparams = _badge2.LayoutParameters;
        badge.SetSingleLine();
        lparams.Width = (int)((bounds.Right - bounds.Left) * 1.25);
    }
    lparams.Height = lparams.Width;
    badge.LayoutParameters = lparams;
}
```

And call it every time you set the badge count:

```
ResetBadgeCount(_yourBadgeInstance, 999);
```

Or make it an extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void ResetBadgeCount(this BottomBarBadge badge, int count)
    {
        badge.Count = count;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lparams;
        using (Rect bounds = new Rect())
        {
            badge.Paint.GetTextBounds(badge.Text, 0, badge.Text.Length, bounds);
            badge.SetSingleLine();
            lparams = badge.LayoutParameters;
            lparams.Width = (int)((bounds.Right - bounds.Left) * 1.25);
        }
        lparams.Height = lparams.Width;
        badge.LayoutParameters = lparams;
    }
}
```

Then you can just call it via:

```
_yourBadgeInstance.ResetBadgeCount(999);
_yourBadgeInstance.ResetBadgeCount(1999);
```

---

To achieve a more "WhatsApp-like" look for the badges like in the image in the question (stretch in it's width but don't increase the height), you can use this code in the `ResetBadgeCount` method instead:

```
private void ResetBadgeCount(BottomBarBadge badge, int count)
{
    badge.Count = count;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lparams;
    using (var bounds = new Rect())
    {
        badge.Paint.GetTextBounds(badge.Text, 0, badge.Text.Length, bounds);
        lparams = badge.LayoutParameters;
        badge.SetSingleLine();
        lparams.Width = (int)Math.Round(badge.Paint.MeasureText(badge.Text) * 1.25);
        var metrics = badge.Paint.GetFontMetrics();
        lparams.Height = (int)Math.Round((metrics.Bottom - metrics.Top) * 1.25);
    }
    if (lparams.Width < lparams.Height)
    {
        lparams.Width = lparams.Height;
    }
    badge.LayoutParameters = lparams;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the workaround causes a `NullReferenceException` when I tap the tab which contains a badge. Please see my edited question

Comment: @DennisSchröer See my updated answer, should fix your issue.